# ReplaceChild vs AppendChild

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to build a large XML data structure using a bunch of different XML files, where I need to both append and replace nodes in different situations. My understanding is that the ReplaceChild method is just like the AppendChild method, but it overwrites the node in question. So, given that this works to append

```
$parentNode.AppendChild($result.xml.ImportNode($temp.xml.SelectSingleNode("//Product[@id='$($node.ID)']/$($firmNode.Name)"), $true)) > $null
```

I tried this to Replace

```
$parentNode.ReplaceChild($result.xml.ImportNode($temp.xml.SelectSingleNode("//Product[@id='$($node.ID)']/$($firmNode.Name)"), $true)) > $null
```

And I am getting "Cannot find overload for "ReplaceChild". I am forced to use PS2.0, so I am thinking there just is no ReplaceChild available? I can RemoveChild and then AppendChild with no problems, but if it is possible to just replace the node that would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass two node arguments to `ReplaceChild`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.replacechild(v=vs.110).aspx

> public virtual XmlNode ReplaceChild(  XmlNode newChild,   XmlNode
>   oldChild )

so the first argument is the new child, the second argument is the existing child you want to replace. The method you call `ReplaceChild` on is the parent node.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. You have to swap object for object.